# Php mysql create database if not exists

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a database. Why is not the db created with this code?

```
$dbname = 'regulations_db';
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","pass");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = '". $dbname ."'"))) {
        echo "Database $dbname already exists.";
    }
    else {
        mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE '". $dbname ."'",$con);
        echo "Database $dbname created.";
    }
```

This is working, but I think the first one is the best practice:

```
if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS regulations_db",$con))
    {
        echo "Database created";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
    }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just do a simple `mysql_select_db()` and if the result is false then proceed with the creation.

As an example, check out [the first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131442/how-do-i-create-a-database-if-it-doesnt-exist-using-php) by another very smart StackOverflower.

```
<?php
// Connect to MySQL
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Make my_db the current database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('my_db', $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
  // If we couldn't, then it either doesn't exist, or we can't see it.
  $sql = 'CREATE DATABASE my_db';

  if (mysql_query($sql, $link)) {
      echo "Database my_db created successfully\n";
  } else {
      echo 'Error creating database: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
  }
}

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Update: now should use mysqli_select_db, right? -- also would it make sense to repeat "$db_selected = mysqli_select_db('my_db', $link);" in the success condition (i.e. now it should work) -- or did you only use it to check for existence of the database and have therefor no further need for it anyway?

Comment: mysql_select_db --> is not recognized for me.

Answer (score 5):

Three steps to fix this:

1. Don’t specify the database name when connecting.
2. Your SQL statement should be CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS php1.
3. Call mysqli_select_db($link, 'php1') to make that the default database for your connection.

Comment: Isn't that what the second code that he describes effectively does?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using MySQLi Object-oriented method, you can use following code, this code is similar to previous answer and only the method is different, I just put this because if anyone using MySQLi Object-oriented method, you can use this code directly.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "mysql_user";
$password = "user_password";
$dbName = "databaseName";

// Connect to MySQL
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// If database is not exist create one
if (!mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbName)){
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE ".$dbName;
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Database created successfully";
    }else {
        echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Furthermore you can refer W3school site [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create.asp)

Good Luck! :D