# PHP MySQL - Error: No Database selected

Tags: php, mysql, create-table

I am trying to read and write to a database. Here is the code I have so far:

```
$mysql = mysqli_connect("example.com", "johndoe", "abc123"); // replace with actual credidentials
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS dbname";
if (!mysqli_query($mysql, $sql)) {
    echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($mysql);
}
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_close($mysql);
$mysql = mysqli_connect("example.com", "johndoe", "abc123", "dbname"); // replace with actual credidentials
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(ID), username CHAR(15), password CHAR(15), email CHAR(50))";
if (!mysqli_query($mysql, $sql)) {
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($mysql);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO Customers(username, password, email) VALUES(" . $username . ", " . $password . ", " . $email . ")";
if (!mysqli_query($mysql, $sql)) {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($mysql);
}
mysqli_close($mysql);
```

However, when I try to run it, it has an error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , )' at line 1
```

Could anybody tell me how to fix this?

Comment: You have to select the db before creating the table..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First check `mysqli_select_db` if it returns false then create database.

try like this:

```
 $mysql = mysqli_connect("example.com", "johndoe", "abc123") or die(mysqli_connect_error()); // replace with actual credidentials

if (!mysqli_select_db($mysql,'hardestgame_accounts')) {
 $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS hardestgame_accounts";
 if (!mysqli_query($mysql, $sql)) {
    echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($mysql);
 }
}
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(ID), username CHAR(15), password CHAR(15), email CHAR(50))";
if (!mysqli_query($mysql, $sql)) {
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($mysql);
}
mysqli_close($mysql);
```

here is a good answer: [Php mysql create database if not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068767/php-mysql-create-database-if-not-exists)

Comment: mysqli_select_db() function doesn't exists.

Comment: Isn't that what I did?

Comment: @Oliver: check this line `if (!mysqli_select_db($mysql,'hardestgame_accounts'))`

Comment: @Awland Liton lol. it does exists. i was suspicious too but www.php.net/mysqli_select_db‎ resolved to "mysqli_select_db doesn't exist. Closest matches:..."  ok... who removed the beta tag from  php.net?! :)

Comment: @Oliver: did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

Please [check syntax of mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli_connect), it takes 4 parameters.You also have to provide database name.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","my_db");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing database in mysqli_connect() call

```
$link = mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the answer is in your error. You didn't select any database. When using this function mysqli_connect specify the database you want to connect to.

Here is the syntax of the function: http://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_mysqli_connect.asp .

1) Create your database outside of your application

2) Specify mysqli_connect with the database you want to select.

You can also use another function called mysqli_select_db . You can find the sytanx here : http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_select_db.asp .

As already stated in the comment, you will also have to replace : "example.com" with your ip address, if you are running locally replace it with 127.0.0.1:3306 , if you didn't change the port when you installed your mysql database / "johndoe" with your database account, you can change that to "root" / "abc123" with your root account password DEFAULT : "" .

Good luck !

Answer (score -1):

Try using [`mysql_select_db`](https://www.php.net/mysql_select_db) in between the database connection and the table creation.

Also, `mysql_` is deprecated, please use `mysqli_` instead

Answer (score -1):

Use ` backticks for MYSQL reserved words...
your table name  is reserved word for MYSQL...
Change your table name.