# Issue with submitting form in Bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have below bootstrap contact form:

```
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Family Name" name="familyname" id="familyname" value="<?php echo $_POST['familyname']; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $_POST['phone']; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="">Submit</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name ="mode" value="submit">
                </div>
            </form>
```

On submit I want to inset to the contact table as below:

```
if (($_POST['mode']) == 'submit'){
    var_dump("Testing if I entered this if statement"); die();

    $add_contact = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `contact` (
    `cont_id`, //it is auto increment id 
    `cont_fname`, 
    `cont_family`, 
    `cont_phone`
    ) VALUES (
    '" . $_POST['firstname'] . "', 
    '" . $_POST['familyname'] . "', 
    '" . $_POST['phone'] . "'
    )") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

}
```

I faced two problems. First of all after clicking on submit button, the program does not get into the if statement? Second what is wrong with the database insert? I tried the insert in a different script and it did not work. I appreciate if you could help.

And here is my connection file that works fine which means I connect to my database:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","contacts");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
```

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['formname'])){......#enter your code here}` ..give method  to form `POST`

Comment: Works after using post method however it does not insert to database, any idea why?

Comment: Set `name` and `value` attributes to submit button and delete hidden field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `method = "POST"` in the `<form>` tag and a hidden type.

```
<form role="form" method = "POST">
<!-- blah3 -->
<input type="hidden" name ="check">
<input type="submit" name ="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

And in your `php` put a `isset`:

```
if (isset($_POST['check'])){
    echo "Im inside the if-statement duh!";

    $add_contact = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `contact` (
    `cont_id`,  
    `cont_fname`, 
    `cont_family`, 
    `cont_phone`
    ) VALUES (
    '" . $_POST['firstname'] . "', 
    '" . $_POST['familyname'] . "', 
    '" . $_POST['phone'] . "'
    )") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

}
```

**EDIT:**

> connection.php:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "yourdbnamehere");

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Source: [PHP: mysqli_connect](https://www.php.net/mysqli_connect)

Comment: It works now after using post and goes into the if statement however it does not insert into database, any idea why?

Comment: @MaryJane remove `die();` as it will kill everything. check the edited answer! :)

Comment: After removing die I still receive this error which doesn't allow any inset "No database selected".

Comment: @MaryJane check your `connection` file with correct `database credentials` check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972146/php-mysql-error-no-database-selected

Comment: Actually I have used the same question you sent me above, to connect to my database but still no results!

Comment: @MaryJane `mysqli_connect` expects four params. check my edit?

Comment: myphpadmin had no username and password so I used this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703996/how-to-find-out-the-username-and-password-for-mysql-database to create a user name and password for the phpmyadmin (so I can use them in the mysqli_connect) however the username and password still not working and I can not log in to the phpmyadmin!

Comment: @MaryJane did you amend the changes? if not did you try putting the username as `"root"` and leaving the password empty as `""`? by default this is what you should be seeing in `config.inc` file `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';` something like I did in the edit now.