# unable to create database, showing unknown database

Tags: php, mysql, database

The application is only able to connect with a manually developed database in phpmyadmin but not able to create a database from the php.

here is the code (install_database.php) for creating that database

```
<?php
$cn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or
        die('Unable to connect. Check connection parameters.');

$sql = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS cars';

mysql_query($sql, $cn) or 
        die(mysql_error($cn));

mysql_select_db('cars') or
        die(mysql_error($cn));

$sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
            user_id             INTEGER UNSIGNED        NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            user_username       VARCHAR(80)             NOT NULL,
            user_password       VARCHAR(80)             NOT NULL,
            user_join_date      INTEGER UNSIGNED        NOT NULL,
            user_age            INTEGER UNSIGNED        NOT NULL,
            user_country        VARCHAR(100)            NOT NULL,

            PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
            )
            ENGINE=MyISAM';

mysql_query($sql,$cn) or 
        die(mysql_error($cn));



?>
```

its showing **unknown database 'cars'** on the browser.
if any additional detail is required please inform.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php mysql create database if not exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068767/php-mysql-create-database-if-not-exists)

Comment: Still can't figure out the reason for not creating the database. How can I verify why is not creating the database?