# creating a databased after checking it doesn't exist in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code however, when the database already exists, I get an empty response and echo doesn't show anything:

```
try
{
    //die('here');

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if (!PDO_select_db($conn, $dbName)){
      echo "Database doesn't exist!";
      $sql = "CREATE DATABASE ".$dbName;
      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Database was created successfully";
      } else {
        echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
      }

  } 
  else {
  echo "Database already exists!";
  }
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

As you see, using Firefox Inspect, in Network tab, I see `No response data available for this request`.
[image]

Expected behavior: since the database already exists, I am expecting to see `Database already exists!` in the Response section of Network tab.

So, my database, named `judges`, exists and using  `$ php -l submit.php` I see that my code has no error.
I can also see this in phpMyAdmin GUI:
[image]

Comment: It's probably an exception that is thrown. What happens in your `catch` block?

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to have anything to do with javascript and ajax.

Comment: @ITgoldman the echo in catch don't show anything in Response tab (if I remove the last else for when the database exists")

Comment: @ITgoldman what do you exactly want me to do?

Comment: @MonaJalal It is still not clear to me what happens in the `catch` section that is missing from this code snippet.

Comment: I usually check if database exists by executing  query `use name_of_db;` and if it throws error then database doesn't exist.

Comment: We don't know what your function `PDO_select_db()` does or what it returns. That's not a standard PDO function, so it must be something implemented in your code.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for pointing that out. I got it from a stackoverflow answer. Basically, I don't know what I should use instead, I intend to only create the database if it doesn't exists beforehand. How should I fix my script? Also, please check my update end of post.

Comment: @BillKarwin I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/9068848/2414957 however, also mysql_select_db is not recognized as a function. What is the function that I should use?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to use a database in PDO is to name it in the [DSN](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) when you connect:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=name_of_db", $username, $password);
```

If you want to change the default database, you can use [`PDO::exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) to run a [`USE <database>` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/use.html):

```
$conn->exec("USE name_of_db");
```

You can't use `mysql_select_db()` because all the `mysql_*` functions were deprecated in PHP 5.5 (circa 2013), and removed from PHP in version 7.0 (2015). You should use more current resources to learn PHP and PDO.

---

PS:
Honestly, I don't add CREATE DATABASE to my application code. The database just better exist. If it doesn't, references to it will throw an exception, so I create the database manually before I deploy my application. Since that needs to happen only once, it's a waste of time and lines of code to check that the database exists during every PHP request.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I am using a new version of PHP and the functions I was using were obsolete.

The code below works:

```
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbName = "judges";

try
{

  $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password);
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  // If database is not exist create one
  if (!mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbName)){
      $sql = "CREATE DATABASE ".$dbName;
      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
          echo "Database created successfully";
      }else {
          echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
      }
  } 


}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "in catch block";
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Please do not mix object-oriented and procedural mysqli styles in your code. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php  you should not be `die()`ing or `echo`ing raw error messages. What makes you think that MySQLi will throw a PDO exception?  I feel like you might be blindly copy-pasting too much code that you don't understand.

Comment: good catch, how come user with so many points can do that she's expert in python i see